# Solving for frequency deviation, $\Delta f $ (FM modulation)

Tags: homework, self-study, proof, frequency-modulation

I'm sorry if I posted this in the wrong section. I solved the question and got $50\textrm{kHz}$, but the solution says it is $100\textrm{kHz}$ without any proof.

Im asking for someone to tell me which is correct.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE!  Which particular question are you trying to answer. There are many on that page.

Comment: I am trying to answer exercise 3, part 1. (The one with the line figure and VCO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the standard definition of [frequency deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_deviation) as the

> "maximum instantaneous difference between an FM modulated frequency and the nominal carrier frequency"

then for the given example you indeed have $\Delta f=50\;\text{kHz}$, because the nominal carrier frequency is $f_c=10\;\text{MHz}$, the maximum frequency is $f_c+\Delta f=10.05\;\text{MHz}$, and the minimum frequency is $f_c-\Delta f=9.95\;\text{MHz}$.

Comment: That is how I solved it, found equation of the line and found min and max frequencies from it. Your answer makes it clear, thank you :)